# Poisson's eqution and radial symmetry

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

[image]

I don't understand why $\Phi$ does not depend on $\theta$ or $\phi$. On the boundary it makes sense because $\Phi$ on the boundary does not depend on any of the variables. I get that the sphere looks the same no matter what angle it is you're looking at it from. However aren't the points inside the sphere fixed relevant to a coordinate axis? What otherwise would be the point in $\theta$ or $\phi$ in spherical polar coordinates?

[image]

Comment: In this special case they just want to explore $$\frac{{{\partial ^2}\phi }}{{\partial {r^2}}} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{{{\partial}\phi }}{{\partial r}} = 2$$
to have this radial symmetry. So they must set other partials to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you arrive at a solution in your initial coordinate system.

Now, if you rotate your coordinate system and establish a new set of spherical coordinates, there is nothing about the sphere that appears to change.

The Laplacian operator is invariant under rotations.

And the "forcing function," namely $2$ is independent of the coordinates.

Thus, you have complete spherical symmetry and therefore, the solution can not be dependent on $\theta$ or $\phi$.

Comment: Do you mind explaining this with reference to the picture I have added to the OP. In the second picture I left $\phi$ alone so that I could draw it in 2D and rotated the coordinate system by $\pi/2$. If I can understand why $\Phi$ doesn't depend on $\theta$ in this case it will make sense if extended to changes in $\phi$. I understand when rotating a sphere it **appears** nothing has changed but I am concerned about what values $\Phi$ takes inside the sphere.

Comment: Well, ask yourself, "what physics changes are there as I move in the sphere by changing either $\theta$ or $\phi$?"  By the way, if you write a prospective solution in terms of a complete set of eignenfunctions of the Laplacian (i.e., spherical harmonics), you will find that the coefficients on all terms, except the ones that are independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$, are zero.